# Jenkins не видит новый Python, но при вызове из командной строки он есть

Tags: python, linux, jenkins, centos7

Установил python 3.9.5 на удалённый сервер с jenkins. При подключении к серверу по ssh новый python отображается в командной строке

```
$ python3.9 --version
Python 3.9.5
```

Но при выполнении той же команды из jenkins, сборка падает

```
+ python3.9 --version
/tmp/jenkins825221091786152728.sh: line 2: python3.9: command not found
```

Помогите понять в чём дело. Помимо python 3.9.5, стоит 3.6.4 и 2.7.5, вызываются командами python3 и python соответственно

Comment: Ну может в путях новый питон не прописался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не понял причину, но помогла чистовая переустановка jenkins